# Why WsHttpbindings giving error as "soap header action was not understood" but not the basichttpbinding?

Tags: .net, wcf, soap, wshttpbinding, basichttpbinding

I have  developed a WCF service which is in wsHttpBinding. When I try to consume it, I am getting error as "soap header action was not understood". But when I use the same service in BasicHttpBinding, I am able to consume the service. Can anyone please explain this properly?

Answer (score 2):

The WS-* protocol stack requires SOAP 1.2."SOAP header action not understood" is the error when a SOAP 1.1 message is processed by a service set up with SOAP 1.2 bindings (WsHttpBinding). If the client can't send a SOAP 1.2 request, you'll have to expose a SOAP 1.1 interface, which is what basicHttpBinding is.